# vim autocmd closing specific tab

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Context: I am currently writing some vim plugins.

I am trying to trigger a function when closing a **specific** tab, using vimscript in Vim 8.2.
Let's say I have a tab, which number is stored in a variable:

```
let s:tabnumber = tabpagenr()
```

I want, whenever I close this one tab, to trigger an autocmd, but not on any other tab.
Do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your design is broken, as so-called tab numbers are actually current position indexes, which is a subject to change due to numerous user actions.
2. Therefore, an autocommand `TabClosed` has no meaningful `amatch`, and hence you must trap it using "a wildcard" and afterwards check it yourself if it's your tab of interest was closed or some other one. Needless to repeat, while doing this you must not rely on tab numbers.

Comment: Alright I see, any idea on how to somehow tag this tab in order to find it back? I know my window manager does this, maybe vim can do it too?

Comment: @Soulthym For example, using `:h tabpage-variable`. However, you should think twice if you really want to work with a specific tab. Normally you stick to buffers leaving layout stuff to a user.